# R sink to .csv with predefined width

Tags: r, csv, sink

I've got an R script that exports a data frame and some other lines to .csv file using sink.  Another script collects the data from multiple csv's exported in this way.

These scripts need to be used by multiple users, and while the process works fine for me, it has introduced errors when I asked someone else to run it.

The reason seems to be that the sink function apparently exports the data frame at the width of the console window in RStudio, so in the event that the width of the data frame is too wide, it wraps it over multiple lines in exactly the same way that printing to the console window would.  Consequently, the second script isn't locating the data it is looking for.

Is it possible to ensure that the output to .csv disregards the display window width and makes the file wide enough to store all columns, regardless of who the user is or what settings they have on RStudio or elsewhere?

Edit:  here is some example code that reproduces the problem:

```
my.df <- data.frame(a = c(1:10), 
       b = c(1:10),
       c = c(1:10),
       d = c(1:10), 
       e = c(1:10), 
       f = c(1:10), 
       g = c(1:10), 
       h = c(1:10), 
       i = c(1:10), 
       j = c(1:10))
sink(file = "test.txt")
print("title information")
print(my.df)
cat("\n")
print("... some other lines...")
sink(file = NULL)
```

Running this code 1) with a wide screen layout, and 2) with a narrower screen screen layout, produces different output in the text file.

Comment: some sample code would be great! I might be wrong but it seems dubious that using sink would be the best approach for making csvs

Comment: @Mark, yes you would think so and if it was just the data frame that I had to export I would agree, but there are additional lines that need to be added at the end so sink seemed the best option, and it was working fine at least for me.  Unfortunately I can't provide a working example for privacy reasons, but I'll see if I can reproduce the problem using some other data.

Comment: even I'd say binding some rows onto the end would be a more robust option than using sink

Comment: I'd even say appending text to the end of a csv isn't a particularly great thing to do anyway, because then you'll have a malformed csv, with a number of rows with only one column

Comment: Again, I would normally agree, but the purpose here is to produce a report that includes the data and some additional information, with a layout optimised for readability.  The other script anticipates this layout and reads the relevant portions.

Comment: how many lines of information are you adding to the end @Phenomniverse?

Comment: " the purpose here is to produce a report that includes the data and some additional information, with a layout optimised for readability" Why are you not using knitr?

Comment: @Mark about 25 extra lines.  The data frame part of the report is only 10 rows of 10 columns, so the bulk of it is in the extra lines.

Comment: the fact that you're feeding it into something else makes me think it's not so much a report as an intermediate data object, which makes this usage make less sense. Instead of intentionally deforming your data, and then having to create a buggy program to parse your reports, keep your data in a format easily readable by a machine, and the amount of bugs you have now (and into the future) will go down dramatically. It will also be easier for users and developers, and be more robust to future changes

Comment: @Mark I hear you, but it is actually a daily report that needs to be readable.  It's just that the results of that report go into a further downstream analysis pipeline.

Comment: It seems like the current situation is such that you're trying to make something be a data object and also a report, and it's not doing either particularly well. Can you break those two things out into separate files/functions (e.g. by creating reports on the fly, from an underlying structured dataset when people request it?). Or maybe generating a structured dataset and then an unstructured knitr report for non-technical people)

Comment: That seems like a really long work around for a pretty simple problem, which is just that sink is splitting each row of the data table into multiple rows.  The easiest fix is just to educate users to make sure they've got their window stretched wide enough when generating the report, but if there's a simple way to change the behaviour of sink() I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other interested parties, the width can be set by using the line:

```
options(width=400)
```

before using the sink() command.

Answer (score 1):

`sink` is not designed for creating reports. As I suggested in a comment, use knitr. Here is how you do that with RStudio:

Step 1. Create an R Notebook file.

Step 2. The file content should look like this (customize as needed, e.g., by setting a width for the output):

````
---
title: "title information"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    code_download: true
---
```{r, echo = FALSE, comment = ""}
my.df <- data.frame(a = c(1:10), 
       b = c(1:10),
       c = c(1:10),
       d = c(1:10), 
       e = c(1:10), 
       f = c(1:10), 
       g = c(1:10), 
       h = c(1:10), 
       i = c(1:10), 
       j = c(1:10))
```
```{r, echo = FALSE, comment = "", purl=FALSE}
print(my.df)
```

... some other lines...
````

Step 3. Knit the file. This will create an HTML file that your clients can view in their internet browser. We have embedded the Markdown code, i.e., there is a download button when you view the HTML file.

Step 4. You can recover the code creating the data.frame with `knitr::purl("test.Rmd", documentation = 0)`. You may want to use `dput` in your markdown file.

I recommend the R Markdown Cookbook: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/

Comment: While I appreciate the time you've taken, my question remains "is it possible to ensure that the sink output to .csv (or .txt) disregards the display window width"?  I don't have time to try an implement this solution that you have recommended, and I am not interested in producing a html document.

Comment: I'm not interested in regurgitating google search results, where you can already find the literal answer to your question (it took me 5 seconds). I wrote this answer to have it hopefully turn up in these search results and promote better practices.